# How can I get an users website with PyGithub?

Tags: pygithub

How can I get an GitHub users website (the one displayed on a users profile) with [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (Github API v3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website of user/organization profiles is accessible via [`NamedUser.blob`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/NamedUser.html#github.NamedUser.NamedUser.blog).

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly in pygithub. html_url is a property of NamedUser. Below codes could get the user in the organization.

```
def get_user_html(user_name):
    gh = Github(base_url=url, login_or_token=token)
    org = gh.get_organization(org_name)
    mems = org.get_members()
    for mem in mems:
        if mem.name == user_name:
            print(mem.html_url)
```